# How do I put row data from a database into a PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a website to learn PHP and databases and I've got a database with a foreign key from the users table linked to a table of organisations. I linked to the numerical ID of the organisation. But when I throw this information into a variable in PHP, it only outputs the number and I'd like it to use the row data (only 2 columns: ID and Name). Preferably I'd like to know how to get the name on its own, the ID on its own and both together. If this isn't possible, any workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

Here's some code and data:

```
# part of a signup script
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {
    
    require 'dbh.inc.php';
    
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $invcode = $_POST['invcode'];
    $confirmpassword = $_POST['cpwd'];
    $idoforg = substr($invcode, 0, 3);
#   $orgnameinsert = "SELECT Organisation FROM id_org WHERE idorg='$idoforg'";
# the commented variable was a theory I was thinking of that didn't work
# because it couldn't insert anything, I presume because my code is wrong
```

After this there's a bunch of checks which have nothing to do with my question.

```
else { 
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidusers, emailusers, pwdusers, invcode, idorganisation) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror4");
    exit();
                                        }

else {
    $hashedpwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $username, $email, $hashedpwd, $invcode, $idoforg); 
# I did try to put $orgnameinsert in here but it stopped any data 
# going in at all
                                                                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
```

So to make myself a little bit clearer, I want to reference the data in the row of a table called `id_org` with a foreign key that points to a column called `idorg` that has data in the next column (same row) called `Organisation` and use that varchar data to input in my `users` table in a column called `OrgName`.

[image: Users Table]
[image: id_org table]

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and looks clunky and out of place when used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on. Parts of this code aren't even visible in the question due to utterly chaotic formatting.

Comment: Adding important comments in a screenshot in illegibly tiny red text is not helping anyone. Please, **use plain-text**. Avoid images unless the problem is specifically visual, like CSS issues.

Comment: You also need to read up on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as things like `OrgName` should not exist in your users table. You're trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: This was just an idea I had to test. It's more that when I put the `idorganisation` into a session in PHP it only outputs the number and I can't figure out how to get at the text its linked to, so I had the idea to put the text in its own column as a workaround but I couldn't figure it out. Sorry about bad indentation, I tried to just copy and paste but it came out messy.

Comment: `use that varchar data to input in my users table in a column called OrgName.`...that isn't necessary. If you are outputting data about the user and you want the name of the organisation at the same time then you write a JOIN query which joins the user and organisation tables together using the organisation ID. It sounds like you've already set the foreign key up, so maybe the missing link for you is understanding that you can make a JOIN query in order to utilise that foreign key relationship.